# Stopping sweet alert 2 from appearing after the last pair of cards are found

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I currently facing this problem where 2 sweetalert are appearing one after another after the last pair of cards are found. I just recently add setTimeOut to the sweetalert because my professor wants the sweet alert to not immediately appear after finding a pair of cards but now as I mention earlier when I found the last pairs of cards 2 sweetalert are appearing one after another. by the way I used sweetalert 2. Here is my code:

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.memory-card')

let hasFlippedCard = false
let lockBoard = false
let firstCard, secondCard
let matchCounter = 0
let timerCtrl = null // store the return value of setInterval

function flipCard() {
  if (lockBoard) return
  if (this === firstCard) return

  this.classList.add('flip')

  if (!hasFlippedCard) {
    hasFlippedCard = true
    firstCard = this

    return
  }

  secondCard = this
  checkForMatch()
}

function checkForMatch() {
  let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.framework === secondCard.dataset.framework
  if (isMatch) {
    matchCounter += 1
    disableCards()
    setTimeout(function(){
      Swal.fire({
        imageUrl: 'https://unsplash.it/400/200',
        imageWidth: 400,
        imageHeight: 200,
        imageAlt: 'Custom image',
        html: '<a href="//sweetalert2.github.io">links</a> ',
        // confirmButtonText: 'Resume Game',
        allowOutsideClick: false,
      }).then(() => {
        time()
      })
    }, 1000);
    
    clearInterval(timerCtrl)
    if (matchCounter == cards.length / 2) {
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Congratualtions!!!',
        text: 'You finish the game ' +
          counterVal +
          ' Moves. Thank you for playing',
        allowOutsideClick: false,
      })
      setTimeout(timerCtrl) // it will stop the timer
    }
  } else {
    unflipCards()
  }
}

function disableCards() {
  firstCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard)
  secondCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard)

  resetBoard()
}

function unflipCards() {
  lockBoard = true

  setTimeout(() => {
    firstCard.classList.remove('flip')
    secondCard.classList.remove('flip')

    resetBoard()
  }, 500)
}

function resetBoard() {
  hasFlippedCard = false
  lockBoard = false
  firstCard = null
  secondCard = null
}

;
(function shuffle() {
  cards.forEach(card => {
    let randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)
    card.style.order = randomPos
  })
})()

cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard))

function restartButton() {
  location.reload()
}
var i = 0

function timer(id) {
  if (id == '1') {
    i++
    if (i === 1) {
      time()
    }
  } else if (id == '2') {
    //dri nimo e butang ang pause nga function
  } else if (id == '3') {
    //function for continue time
  }
}

var numr = 0

function countClick() {
  numr++
  console.log(numr)
}


var minutesLabel = document.getElementById('minutes')
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById('seconds')
var totalSeconds = 0

/*Timer*/
function time() {
  function setTime() {
    ++totalSeconds
    secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60)
    minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60))
  }

  function pad(val) {
    var valString = val + ''
    if (valString.length < 2) {
      return '0' + valString
    } else {
      return valString
    }
  }
  timerCtrl = setInterval(setTime, 1000)
}

var counterVal = 0

function incrementClick() {
  updateDisplay(++counterVal)
}

function resetCounter() {
  counterVal = 0
  updateDisplay(counterVal)
}

function updateDisplay(val) {
  document.getElementById('counter-label').innerHTML = val
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url('https://github.com/FoxyStoat/memory-game/blob/master/assets/img/ignasi_pattern_s.png?raw=true');
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.6);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.memory-game {
  width: 340px;
  height: 340px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  perspective: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
}

.memory-card {
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  height: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* transform: scale(1); */
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.memory-card:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.memory-card.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* padding: 1px; */
  position: absolute;
  /* border-radius: 5px; */
  /* background: #1C7CCC; */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front-face {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.score-panel {
  text-align: left;
  width: 270px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #0d0d0e;
}

.score-panel .stars {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  color: rgb(24, 23, 23);
}

.score-panel .stars li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.score-panel .timer {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

.score-panel .restart {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  .memory-game {
    width: 860px;
    min-height: 880px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 812px) {
  .memory-game {
    width: 860px;
    min-height: 880px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) {
  .memory-game {
    width: 860px;
    min-height: 880px;
  }
}

.swal-wide {
  width: 850px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Memory Game</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href ="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah|Permanent+Marker" >
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>resources/dist/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">
  <h1>Memory Game</h1>
  <section class="score-panel">
            <!-- <ul class="stars">
                <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
            </ul> -->

            <span>Moves <span id = "counter-label">0</span></span>

            <div class="timer">
                <label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label>
            </div>

            <div class="restart">
                <button onclick="restartButton()" class="fa fa-repeat"></button>
            <!-- <div class="col text-center">
                <button button type = "button" class = "btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
            </div> -->
            </div>
        </section>

  <div class="memory-game ">
    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="aurelia">
      <img class="front-face" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/resources/dist/img/fb.png" class = "img-fluid"alt="fb" />
      <img onclick = "incrementClick(); timer('1');" id="back" class="back-face" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/resources/dist/img/card.png" class = "img-fluid"alt="yugioh" />
    </div>

    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="aurelia">
      <img class="front-face" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/resources/dist/img/fb.png" class = "img-fluid"alt="fb" />
      <img onclick = "incrementClick(); timer('1');" id = "back" class="back-face" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/resources/dist/img/card.png" class = "img-fluid"alt="yugioh" />
    </div>

    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="vue">
      <img class="front-face" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/resources/dist/img/js.jpg" class = "img-fluid"alt="js" />
      <img onclick = "incrementClick(); timer('1');" id = "back"id="back" class="back-face" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/resources/dist/img/card.png" class = "img-fluid"alt="yugioh" />
    </div>
              
    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="vue">
      <img class="front-face" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/resources/dist/img/js.jpg" class = "img-fluid"alt="js" />
      <img onclick = "incrementClick(); timer('1');" id="back" class="back-face" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/resources/dist/img/card.png" class = "img-fluid"alt="yugioh" />
    </div>

      
            
  </div> 

</div>
```

and also I want to image of the flipped card to be seen in the sweetalert when the pairs of the card are found. Newbie web developer here. I appreciate any help you can give to me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You first check `if (matchCounter == cards.length / 2)` and if it is true then show the end game popup. If not then show the other popup.

Comment: @aerial301 thank you for your help. the 2nd sweet alert now didn't show up. May I also ask if how will I be able to show the image of the paired cards found in the sweet alert? i cant find any leads to how will i make that happen